# Extracting Values from SQL Strings and Print Them Out

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this Query and I want to extract the info generated and print them out in a ASP.net page that contain WML Card.

```
string queryString = "select st.firstname + ' ' + st.lastname,se.year, c.coursename,c.NumberOfCredits,ri.mark  from Students st inner join RegisteredIn ri on ri.StudentId=st.id inner join Semester se on se.id=ri.SemesterId inner join Courses c on c.id=se.id ";
```

Note : the results will be somthing like

```
First Semester  2010 
Student : Arin Rizk  
Course Name     No. of Credit      Mark
AAA                3            65    
BBB                3            23     
CCC                3            65     
DDD                3            58     
EEE                3            70
```

How can I do it ? please show me.

Comment: Yes , I used a while(reader.Read()) // string _firstname = reader[0].ToString(); // , but couldnt print them .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a model to represent your data:

```
public class StudentCourse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    ... and so on
}
```

then you could create a method that will query your database using ADO.NET and fill a collection of this model:

```
public static IEnumerable<StudentCourse> GetCourses()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select st.firstname + ' ' + st.lastname, se.year, c.coursename, c.NumberOfCredits, ri.mark from Students st inner join RegisteredIn ri on ri.StudentId=st.id inner join Semester se on se.id=ri.SemesterId inner join Courses c on c.id=se.id";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new StudentCourse
                {
                    Name = reader.GetString(0),
                    Year = reader.GetInt32(1),
                    ... and so on
                }; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally you could bind this to a GridView in the page:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    courses.DataSource = GetCourses();
    courses.DataBind();
}
```

and in your code behind you will have the grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="courses" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

or if you don't want to use a Grid view, simply use a `Repeater` and build whatever markup you like from the model.

Comment: dont have a grid view as I will be showing the data in WML card

Comment: Then you could build the markup manually in whatever format you like from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Gridview and Itemtemplate for this...
All You Need to do is to bind your sql query with gridview and create table in itemtemplate according to your requirements.

Comment: I cant use grid views I know I said print them in ASP page but I will create a WML card inside the page and show the results.